# Automorphisms of a character table

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, representation-theory, galois-theory, gap

Consider the character table of the finite group $ G $. Every outer automorphism of $ G $ permutes the characters of $ G $. If some of the characters are non-integral then we can consider the corresponding Galois automorphisms and they will also permute the characters of $ G $.

Do outer automorphisms and Galois automorphisms together generate all possible automorphisms of the character table of $ G $? Is there a name for the group formed by the outer automorphisms and the Galois automorphisms?

For example consider $ SL(2,5) $. There is only one (non-trivial) automorphism of the character table of $ SL(2,5) $. It swaps the two degree $ 2 $ irreps and swaps the two degree $ 3 $ irreps. All characters of $ SL(2,5) $ are defined over $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}) $. The Galois automorphism $ \sqrt{5} \to -\sqrt{5} $ enacts exactly the table automorphism described above. There is also a unique nontrivial outer automorphism of $ SL(2,5) $ and it also enacts exactly the table automorphism described above. So in this case the Galois automorphisms and the outer automorphisms overlap, corresponding to the same table automorphism.

On the other hand consider $ 3.A_6 $. This group has outer automorphism group $ 2^2 $. All characters of $ 3.A_6 $ are defined over $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{-3}) $, so the group of Galois automorphisms is also a $ 2^2 $. However in this case these groups do not totally overlap and they generate $ 2^3 $ different table automorphisms. In particular there are two independent table automorphisms coming from Galois conjugation and then there is also a third independent table automorphism coming from an outer automorphism (this table automorphism swaps the two degree $ 5 $ irreps, which are both integral, lifted from $ A_6 $).

As Jyrki points out I have recently asked other questions on this general theme:

[Distinct characters with the same character values, outer automorphisms and Galois conjugation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4856291/distinct-characters-with-the-same-character-values-outer-automorphisms-and-galo?noredirect=1&lq=1)

and

[Same character values iff related by outer automorphism, for perfect groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4698049/same-character-values-iff-related-by-outer-automorphism-for-perfect-groups)

Comment: Linking to [your other recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4856291/11619), because the general theme is similar. Wish I could say something useful, but you have searched quite a bit already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $G = D_4 \times Q_8$ where $D_4$ is the eight-element dihedral group and $Q_8$ is the eight-element quaternion group. Famously, these have the same character table but are not isomorphic. Fixing a bijection between their conjugacy classes of these groups, and one of their characters, compatible with the character table, we obtain an automorphism of the character table of $D_4 \times Q_8$ - if $i$ is the isomorphism on conjugacy classes then we send the conjugacy class of $(a,b)$ to the conjugacy class of $(i^{-1}(b), i(a))$.

This character table automorphism cannot come from an outer automorphism (or Galois conjugation, since all character values are integers). If it did, the automorphism would send $D_4$ (a union of conjugacy classes) to $Q_8$ (the union of the images of those conjugacy classes) which i

This is part of a general tricks in mathematics that isomorphisms $A \to B$ with unusual properties often give automorphisms of $A\times B$ with unusual properties. This can be used as in this example to construct automorphisms, or in reverse, as in the proofs of the Tate conjecture for morphisms of abelian varieties which shows certain unusual homomorphisms between groups (the Tate modules of abelian varieties) cannot exist, by first using an unusual homomorphism to construct an unusual endomorphism and then showing that unusual endomorphims cannot exist.

Comment: I see so if we wanted an example with $ G $ perfect then we could take $ A=2^3 \rtimes SL(3,2)=\text{PerfectGroup}(1344,1) $ and the nonsplit extension $ B=2^3  \cdot SL(3,2)=\text{PerfectGroup}(1344,2) $ and since $ A $ and $ B $ are perfect group with the same character table then $ G=A \times B $ would be a perfect group with the kind of unusual automorphisms you construct in this example.